# Group by in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am facing this requirement to group by in xslt 2.0.
I have been doing some basic xslt's lately with apply-templates, identity transform and this is my bit advanced case for now.

I would really appreciate the inputs.

**Here is my input XML:**

```
<root>
    <worker>
        <change1>
            <date_of_change>date1</date_of_change>
            <field1>field1</field1>
            <field2>field2</field2>
            <field4>field4</field4>
        </change1>
        <change2>
            <date_of_change>date1</date_of_change>
            <field1>field1</field1>
            <field2>field2</field2>
            <field3>field3</field3>
        </change2>
        <change3>
            <date_of_change>date2</date_of_change>          
            <field2>field2</field2>
            <field3>field3</field3>
            <field4>field4</field4>
        </change3>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <change1>
            <date_of_change>date1</date_of_change>
            <field1>field1</field1>
            <field2>field2</field2>
            <field3>field3</field3>
        </change1>
        <change2>
            <date_of_change>date2</date_of_change>
            <field1>field1</field1>         
            <field3>field3</field3>
        </change2>
        <change3>
            <date_of_change>date2</date_of_change>          
            <field3>field3</field3>
            <field4>field4</field4>
        </change3>
    </worker>
</root>
```

**Here is the expected output XML:**

```
<root>
    <worker>
        <row1>
            <date_of_change>date1</date_of_change>
            <field1>field1</field1>
            <field2>field2</field2>
            <field3>field3</field3>
            <field4>field4</field4>
        </row1>
        <row2>
            <date_of_change>date2</date_of_change>          
            <field2>field2</field2>
            <field3>field3</field3>
            <field4>field4</field4>
        </row2>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <row1>
            <date_of_change>date1</date_of_change>
            <field1>field1</field1>
            <field2>field2</field2>
            <field3>field3</field3>
        </row1>
        <row2>
            <date_of_change>date2</date_of_change>
            <field1>field1</field1>         
            <field3>field3</field3>
            <field4>field4</field4>
        </row2>     
    </worker>
</root>
```

Requirement is when a worker have multiple changes happened on the same date_of_change, then it needs to be grouped to the same row with all the available fields from those multiple changes.

Comment: That's all nice and sweet. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: In XSLT 2.0, xsl:for-each-group is your friend. See https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html

Comment: To get you started a little, try: from the context of `worker`, group elements starting with `change` by `date_of_change`. Inside the for-each-group you will need to create the new "row" (can use `position()` to add row number) element and add another for-each-group to group `current-group()/*` by `name()`. You can also sort inside of each for-each-group.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found the solution by yourself by now, you can try the following XSLT-2.0 stylesheet. The solution was more complicated than assumed at first, so I chose to implement it. It may not be optimal, but you can use it as a starting position for your own needs. It uses two `xsl:for-each-group` instructions to order the elements and one `xsl:element` to construct the `row` element name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>    

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="worker">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'change')]/*[starts-with(local-name(),'field')]" group-by="../date_of_change">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('row',position())}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="../date_of_change" />
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by=".">
                <xsl:sort select="local-name()" />
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its output is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <worker>
      <row1>
         <date_of_change>date1</date_of_change>
         <field1>field1</field1>
         <field2>field2</field2>
         <field3>field3</field3>
         <field4>field4</field4>
      </row1>
      <row2>
         <date_of_change>date2</date_of_change>
         <field2>field2</field2>
         <field3>field3</field3>
         <field4>field4</field4>
      </row2>
   </worker>
   <worker>
      <row1>
         <date_of_change>date1</date_of_change>
         <field1>field1</field1>
         <field2>field2</field2>
         <field3>field3</field3>
      </row1>
      <row2>
         <date_of_change>date2</date_of_change>
         <field1>field1</field1>
         <field3>field3</field3>
         <field4>field4</field4>
      </row2>
   </worker>
</root>
```

Comment: Plus one. What I described in my comment is very similar: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtr7